# How to query a JSON element

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a Postgres database (9.3) and there is a table called `Resources`. In the `Resources` table I have the fields `id` which is an int and `data` which is a JSON type.

Let's say I have the following records in said table.

- 1, {'firstname':'Dave', 'lastname':'Gallant'}
- 2, {'firstname':'John', 'lastname':'Doe'}

What I want to do is write a query that would return all the records in which the data column has a json element with the lastname equal to "Doe"

I tried to write something like this:

```
records = db_session.query(Resource).filter(Resources.data->>'lastname' == "Doe").all()
```

Pycharm however is giving me a compile error on the "->>"

Does anyone know how I would write the filter clause to do what I need?

Comment: Try using `astext` like: `...filter(Resources.c.data["lastname"].astext == "Doe").all()` and see if it works

Comment: That seems to work, though I had to remove the ".c" and just go "Resources.data" directly. Thanks!

Comment: Ah... yes, I usually go with `.c` for column name... glad you have it solved. I will post above as an answer then :-)

Comment: You must use the `.c` if you are not use declarative base I think (`table = sqlalchemy.Table(...)`)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try using [**astext**](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON)

```
records = db_session.query(Resource).filter(
              Resources.data["lastname"].astext == "Doe"
          ).all()
```

Please note that the column MUST have a type of a JSONB. The regular JSON  column will not work.

Comment: Great answer. In addition, the link you gave also provides some other information on how to query nested json (eg query.filter(Resources.data[("lastname", "whatever-other-nested-json-under-lastname")].astext == "Whatever Value").all() ), and how to change data types.

Answer (score 16):

Also you could explicitly cast string to JSON (see [**Postgres JSON type doc**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html)).

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgres import JSON
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast
db_session.query(Resource).filter(
    Resources.data["lastname"] == cast("Doe", JSON)
).all()
```

Comment: You may need to import from dialects.postgresql not just postgres

Comment: For larger tables, dont forget to create a partial index.
Otherwise JSON queries become expensive.

CREATE INDEX idx_lastname_partial ON resourses (((data ->> 'lastname')::VARCHAR(24)))
WHERE (data ->> 'lastname') IS NOT NULL;

Comment: You should use JSONB instead of JSON.

Then you can articulate more sophisticated where clauses such as

Resources.data["size"]  > cast(0.4, JSONB)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using JSON type (not JSONB) the following worked for me:

Note the `'"object"'`

```
    query = db.session.query(ProductSchema).filter(
        cast(ProductSchema.ProductJSON["type"], db.String) != '"object"'
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

According [sqlalchemy.types.JSON](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON), you can do it like this

```
from sqlalchemy import JSON
from sqlalchemy import cast
records = db_session.query(Resource).filter(Resources.data["lastname"] == cast("Doe", JSON)).all()
```

Answer (score 3):

I have some GeoJSON in a JSON (not JSONB) type column and none of the existing solutions worked, but as it turns out, in version 1.3.11 some new data casters were added, so now you can:

```py
records = db_session.query(Resource).filter(Resources.data["lastname"].as_string() == "Doe").all()
```

Reference: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON

> Casting JSON Elements to Other Types
>
> Index operations, i.e. those invoked by calling upon the expression
> using the Python bracket operator as in some_column['some key'],
> return an expression object whose type defaults to JSON by default, so
> that further JSON-oriented instructions may be called upon the result
> type. However, it is likely more common that an index operation is
> expected to return a specific scalar element, such as a string or
> integer. In order to provide access to these elements in a
> backend-agnostic way, a series of data casters are provided:
>
> ```
> Comparator.as_string() - return the element as a string
>
> Comparator.as_boolean() - return the element as a boolean
>
> Comparator.as_float() - return the element as a float
>
> Comparator.as_integer() - return the element as an integer
> ```
>
> These data casters are implemented by supporting dialects in order to
> assure that comparisons to the above types will work as expected, such
> as:
>
> ```py
> # integer comparison
> data_table.c.data["some_integer_key"].as_integer() == 5
>
> # boolean comparison
> data_table.c.data["some_boolean"].as_boolean() == True
> ```

Comment: What about if I have a `Big | Long Integer` and doen't fill in a `Integer` type?

Comment: This commentary is out of bounds from the question scope. but I found an error while compare using the `as_integer` function, so I pick this expression `cast(Table.column, JSONB)['json_property'].as_numeric(13, 0) == number`, the `as_numeric` from [SQLAlchemy Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON.Comparator.as_integer) helps!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON), pre version 1.3.11, the most robust way should be like this, as it works for multiple database types, e.g. SQLite, MySQL, Postgres:

```
from sqlalchemy import cast, JSON, type_coerce, String

db_session.query(Resource).filter(
    cast(Resources.data["lastname"], String) == type_coerce("Doe", JSON)
).all()
```

From version 1.3.11 onward, type-specific casters is the new and neater way to handle this:

```
db_session.query(Resource).filter(
    Resources.data["lastname"].as_string() == "Doe"
).all()
```

Comment: Thanks @Xuan this is the only answer that worked for me