# SQLAlchemy cannot query json - 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'as_text'

Tags: json, postgresql, filter, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am trying to write a query using SQLAlchemy that searches using a JSON field like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29975187/5953826):

```
records = db_session.query(Resource).filter(
              Resources.data["lastname"].astext == "Doe"
          ).all()
```

So in my case I wrote:

```
records = session.query(Watch).filter(
    Watch.filter_data['session_uuid'].as_text == keys['session_uuid'],
)
```

Which gives me the result `AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'as_text'`.

I also tried modifying my code like this:

```
records = session.query(Watch).filter(
    Watch.filter_data.as_text == keys['session_uuid'],
)
```

`AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Watch.filter_data has an attribute 'as_text'`

Basically, I can't do any JSON queries at all, and I have no idea why at this point. I noticed that in the above code example, they are using `Resource` and `Resources` - two separate objects, but I have no idea what the implementation of each looks like so that does not help me much.

I used Alembic to define the field as follows: `sa.Column('filter_data', sa.JSON(), nullable=False),`

And my mapping of this row looks like this:

```
class Watch(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'watch'
    filter_data = Column(sa.JSON(), nullable=False)
    filter_type = Column(sa.Text(), nullable=False)
```

Presumably, I am not supposed to use `Watch.filter_data` in my query at all, but what what am I actually supposed to filter with in that case? There are many examples in the documentation where a mapped class is filtered using an attribute of that mapped class

For example:

```
q = session.query(User).filter(User.name == 'fred')
```

Filtering like this works fine for me. Do you have any idea what I need to do to get this working with JSON queries instead of being limited to direct string comparisons?

Edit: I also found the following. If I use

```
session.query(Watch).filter(sa.Column('filter_data', JSON(), nullable=False)['session_uuid'].astext == keys['session_uuid']).all()
```

Then my query will work.

But if I use

```
session.query(Watch).filter(Watch.__table__.c.filter_data['session_uuid'].astext == keys['session_uuid']).all()
```

The query fails. This in spite of the fact that I defined filter_data as

```
op.create_table(
    'watch',
    sa.Column('filter_data', JSON(astext_type=sa.Text()), nullable=False),
)
```

The columns should, in theory, have the exact same type, but I can't make a query using the field type that alembic thinks this has

So possibly this is an issue with how alembic is processing the types I gave to the field.

Comment: `Watch.filter_data['session_uuid'].as_text` would of course fail, since `as_text` is a typo. Note that the type you use in your alembic migration (the `op.create_table(...)`) does not affect your model, which would seem to be using the generic `sqlalchemy.types.JSON` type that for the time being lacks the `astext` conversion.

Comment: @IljaEverilä is there any way to get normal String from json field instead of raw unicode via casting with that lack of `astext` for generic JSON type?